How to create a variable that compares between pairs of other variables and counts the number of times one is greater than the other in R?
I have a dataframe that has variables called month1, month2, etc., with corresponding variables called max1, max2, etc. I want to create a new variable called count which stores a count for each instance where month_x is greater than max_x. Each row has a matching number of month and max values, such that if month3 is NA, max3 will also be NA. Here is a minimal reproducible example of the data:
id <- c("Lars","Susan","Juan")
month1 <- c(1,1,1)
month2 <- c(2,2,2)
month3 <- c(NA,3,3)
max1 <- c(0,0,2)
max2 <- c(3,1,3)
max3 <- c(NA,2,4)
df <- data.frame(id,month1,month2,month3,max1,max2,max3)

The new variable count should be 1 for Lars, 2 for Susan, and 0 for Juan

Are you sure the count for Susan is 2 and not 3?

A tidy solution:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

pivot_longer(df, -id,
             names_pattern="(.+)(\\d+)",
             names_to=c(".value", "set")) |>
  mutate(count=sum(month>max, na.rm=TRUE), .by=id) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=set, values_from=c(month,max), names_sep="")


# A tibble: 3 × 8
  id    count month1 month2 month3  max1  max2  max3
  <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Lars      1      1      2     NA     0     3    NA
2 Susan     3      1      2      3     0     1     2
3 Juan      0      1      2      3     2     3     4


Alternative using rowSums and grep:
df$count <- rowSums(df[,grep('^month', names(df), value=TRUE)] > 
                    df[,grep('^max', names(df), value=TRUE)], na.rm=TRUE)
df
     id month1 month2 month3 max1 max2 max3 count
1  Lars      1      2     NA    0    3   NA     1
2 Susan      1      2      3    0    1    2     3
3  Juan      1      2      3    2    3    4     0


Fantastic! Thank you

A stable solution using base R (if code stability is important to you)
lapply(1:3, function(x){
  df[ , paste0("month", x)] > df[ , paste0("max", x)]}) |>
  do.call("cbind.data.frame", args= _) |>
  rowSums(x= _, na.rm= TRUE) |>
  cbind.data.frame(df, count= _)

# Output
      id month1 month2 month3 max1 max2 max3 count
1  Lars      1      2     NA    0    3   NA     1
2 Susan      1      2      3    0    1    2     3
3  Juan      1      2      3    2    3    4     0


In the question it is said that sum for Susan is 2, although if I get it right it is actually 3.

Be careful hard-coding 1:3 since the OP hinted that there may be more than 3. "...variables called month1, month2, etc.,"

@Edward Yes, my answer refers to the question as it stands and must be adapted if the actual data differs from dummy data

You can iterate over them in parallel using map2:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df |>
  mutate(count = rowSums(map2_dfr(pick(starts_with("month")), pick(starts_with("max")), `>`), na.rm = T))

Or you can iterate over your months columns and use the column name to get the corresponding max column:
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df |>
  mutate(count = rowSums(across(starts_with("month"), \(x) x > pick(paste0("max", parse_number(cur_column())))), na.rm = T))

Output
#      id month1 month2 month3 max1 max2 max3 count
# 1  Lars      1      2     NA    0    3   NA     1
# 2 Susan      1      2      3    0    1    2     3
# 3  Juan      1      2      3    2    3    4     0

